# io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Failed to open 3

Tags: java, android, realm

I was trying to make a backup for my realm database then I got this error and pointing out at `realms.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);`. I thought maybe I got this error because I'm trying to put 3 realms in one file or something like that. If so how can I make 3 realms backup in one file? if not how can I make it run?
Here is the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jmnapps.expensetracker, PID: 4987
io.realm.exceptions.RealmIOException: Failed to open 3
    at io.realm.internal.Group.nativeWriteToFile(Native Method)
    at io.realm.internal.Group.writeToFile(Group.java:216)
    at io.realm.Realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(Realm.java:1077)
    at io.realm.Realm.writeCopyTo(Realm.java:1057)
    at com.jmnapps.expensetracker.ui.accounts.AccountsFragment.BackupCategories(AccountsFragment.java:281)
    at com.jmnapps.expensetracker.ui.accounts.AccountsFragment$3.onClick(AccountsFragment.java:208)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

and here is my code in executing realm backup

```
    public static AccountsFragment newInstance(){
    return new AccountsFragment();
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public AccountsFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
    btnSync = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnsync);
    btnRestore = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnrestore);
    btnBackup = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnBackup);
    btnLogout=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
    userPicture=(CircleImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.userprofilepic);
    userName = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.personName);
    userEmail=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.personEmail);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mMainActivityListener.setMode(MainActivity.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    mMainActivityListener.setTitle("Account");

    //GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext()).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    mCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
   // mCategoriesAdapter = new CategoriesAdapter(mCategoryList, this);


    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getContext()).build();
    // Get a Realm instance for this thread
    realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);

    expenseList  = realm.where(Expense.class).findAll();
    categoryList  = realm.where(Category.class).findAll();
    reminderList  = realm.where(Reminder.class).findAll();


    String facebookUserId = "";
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String fbuserName = user.getDisplayName();
    String fbuserEmail = user.getEmail();
    Uri fbuserPhoto = user.getPhotoUrl();

    // find the Facebook profile and get the user's id
    for(UserInfo profile : user.getProviderData()) {
        // check if the provider id matches "facebook.com"
        if(FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID.equals(profile.getProviderId())) {
            facebookUserId = profile.getUid();
        }
    }
    String photoUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookUserId + "/picture?height=500";


    userName.setText(fbuserName);
    userEmail.setText(fbuserEmail);
    Picasso.get()
            .load(fbuserPhoto)
            .into(userPicture);

    //userName.setText(fbuserName);
    //userEmail.setText(fbuserEmail);
    //Picasso.get()
            //.load(fbuserPhoto)
            //.into(userPicture);



    btnSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    btnRestore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    btnBackup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BackupCategories();

        }
    });
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dlogout = new Dialog(getContext());
            Dlogout.setContentView(R.layout.layout_logout);
            Dlogout.setTitle("Personal Expense Tracker");

            btnOkay = (Button)Dlogout.findViewById(R.id.btnokay);
            btnOkay.setEnabled(true);

            btnCancel=(Button)Dlogout.findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
            btnCancel.setEnabled(true);

            btnOkay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    userName.setText("");
                    userEmail.setText("");
                    userPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultuser);
                    eraseCategories();


                    //SIGN OUT
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SignInActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    ((Activity) getActivity()).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                }
            });
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Dlogout.dismiss();
                }
            });
            Dlogout.show();
            }
    });

}
public void eraseCategories() {
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            RealmResults<Expense> expdel = realm.where(Expense.class).findAll();
            RealmResults<Category> catdel = realm.where(Category.class).findAll();
            RealmResults<Reminder> remdel = realm.where(Reminder.class).findAll();
            expdel.clear();
            catdel.clear();
            remdel.clear();

        }
    });
}
public void BackupCategories() {
    RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    Realm realms = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    File exportRealmFile;
    EXPORT_REALM_PATH.mkdirs();
    try {
        // create a backup file
        exportRealmFile = new File(EXPORT_REALM_PATH, EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME);

        // if backup file already exists, delete it
        exportRealmFile.delete();

        // copy current realm to backup file
        realms.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String msg = "File exported to Path: " + EXPORT_REALM_PATH + "/" + EXPORT_REALM_FILE_NAME;
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, msg);

    realms.close();


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a conditition to check if the backup file exists before deleting.
You delete each time you try to store so it can't because the file doesn't exit.

Comment: I try to remove the `exportRealmFile.delete();` just to try if it is the delete that causing the trouble but same error I get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me.

```
   public static void SaveFile(String folder, String file, byte[] data) {

    try {
        File del = new File(folder+file);
        //check if the file exist 
        if (del.exists())
            del.delete();

        //create new folder if not exist
        createRep(folder);

        //save the file
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();           
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("err", "error");

    }
}


private static void createRep(String directory){
    boolean isRepExists = false;
    File sdcard = new File("/sdcard");
    String[] sdcardContent = sdcard.list();
    int i=0;
    while(i<sdcardContent.length && !isRepExists){
        if(sdcardContent[i].compareTo(directory)==0)
            isRepExists = true;
        i++;
    }
    File rep = new File(directory);
    if(isRepExists)
        rep.delete();

    rep.mkdirs();
}
```

Call the `SaveFile(....)` method with your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine I just need to use Physical Android Device and not a emulator. Because its having trouble in storage directory